# Laravel deploying

Tags: php, laravel

My app is not working on the production server. It looks like it fails to autload some classes.

```
// app/config/app.php
    'Route'           => 'Extended\Route',

// app/library/extended/Route.php
    <?php namespace Extended {}

    class Route extends ... {}

// app/start/global.php
    ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
        ...
        app_path().'/library',
        ...
    ));

// composer.json
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
                ...
                "app/library",
                ...
        ]
    },
```

I'm receiving this error
**Class 'Extended\Route' not found**

**Edit:**
Deleting the vendors folder and reinstalling all dependencies fixed this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this fixes those kind of errors for Laravel:

```
cd /your/application/dir

rm bootstrap/compiled.php

rm -rf vendor

rm composer.lock

composer install --no-dev
```